# Json-sever GET requests keep firing

Tags: json, reactjs, api, json-server

I've set up a json-server locally on my machine to use as a mock API for an app that I'm creating. I'm running the server on Port 3004 whilst my app is running on Port 3000. The app functions as expected; however, on inspecting the terminal on which the server is running, I noticed that GET requests are continuously being called every millisecond - see image below:

[image]

Is this normal behaviour? I would expect the GET request to be called just once, as per my code below. The GET request is part of a React app and is called inside of useEffect.

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://localhost:3004/invoices',
        {
            headers : { 
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
        },
    }
    )
    .then(function(response){
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(myJson){
        setData(myJson);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error:", error);
      });
  });
```

Comment: You should add a dependency array to useEffect. Pass empty array like so: useEffect(() => {}, []). Empty array means - execute only once on mounting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a dependency to your `useEffect`, for example, if you want it to fire only on the first render, you would write it like

```
useEffect(() => {
fetch('http://localhost:3004/invoices',
    {
        headers : { 
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
    },
}
)
.then(function(response){
    return response.json();
})
.then(function(myJson){
    setData(myJson);
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error:", error);
  });
},[]);
```

More likely, you will want the effect to fire off when something changes, in that case, add the dependecy to the square brackets like so...

```
useEffect(() => {
fetch('http://localhost:3004/invoices',
    {
        headers : { 
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
    },
}
)
.then(function(response){
    return response.json();
})
.then(function(myJson){
    setData(myJson);
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error:", error);
  });
},[someState]);
```